# Export a certificate on Windows Server 2016

Tags: powershell, certificate, windows-server-2016

I working on configuring Active Directory following [this](https://www.dbaplus.ca/2018/08/oracle-database-18c-password.html) guide. Step 5 of this guide is 'Run certutil utility on Active Directory Server to export the certificate' with the following command:

```
certutil -ca.cert cacert.bin
```

but on Windows Server 2016 it fails with message 'CertUtil: The system cannot find the file specified.' because there is no 'certutil.exe' in C:/Windows/System32.

If I start this command in PowerShell console it also fails with message 'CertUtil: Too many arguments'.

So I got stuck with step 5 and can't figure out how to do it on Windows Server 2016 and I wonder if anyone can comment this.

Comment: Why are you not just exporting it from the certificate store using the GUI?  Is there a reason you must use the utility in question?

Comment: @Ramhound honestly I am not sure what action should I do in GUI

Comment: certutil can be used on any Windows OS version. If you have not installed, AD Certificate Services on a server or developer tools on a workstation, that have it as part of that tools (i.e., Office Developer Tools, Visual Studio, etc.), then, you have to download it manually. You can also just copy the certutil.exe from any machine(s) which has it. Just search for it. The steps to do this via the GUI is fully documented on MS websites and many other blogs and youtube videos all over the web.